# Kotlin Arrow for nullable booleans

Tags: kotlin

I have a lot of checks of type `if (obj?.bool == true)` because the boolean is nullable. What's the more elegant way to replace it for example with Arrow?

Comment: Is `obj` a `Boolean?`? Or is `obj` an `Object?` with a `Boolean` property called `bool`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you're asking about a `Boolean?` (a nullable Boolean value), then you don't need Arrow, this plain Kotlin code works:

```
if (bool?:false) {
  // This code is run only if bool is not null and true
} else {
  // This code is run if bool is null or false
}
```

If you're asking about an `Object?` (a nullable object) with a Boolean val property, then the equivalent code would be:

```
if (obj?.bool?:false) {
  // This code is run only if obj is not null and obj.bool is true
} else {
  // This code is run if obj is null or obj.bool is false
}
```